# Can someone, please, help me to solve this level of the game „Flow Mania”?

Tags: visual, grid-deduction

[image: Level 114 of the game „Flow Mania”]

It's very hard for me to solve this level. I just can't figure it out!

<sub>Rules: Draw a lines to connect like-colored dots. A complete solution will utilize every empty square in the grid.</sub>

Comment: Could you at least give us a hint what the rules are? Currently the only way to find out is to look at the answer, which spoils the puzzle somewhat.

Comment: I've searched answers for this level and I didn't found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a little bit rough but I think this should work

> [image]

Comment: A key part of this game is figuring out which routes to fill in first and why. It may improve the answer if you give some of that thinking as hints. For instance, I would start by looking at the bottom half and what the light pink, light blue and orange connections appear to be forced to do.

Comment: rot13: Gur H-ghea va gur oyhr yvar vf irel naablvat. V pna svaq fvk qvssrerag jnlf sbe gur oyhr, cvax naq erq yvarf gb svyy gung nern.

Comment: @TeodosiuCezar Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green check mark next to it.